# How to enter a new line in a multiline Flutter TextField whose textinputaction is textinputaction.done?

Tags: flutter, textfield

The code below creates a Flutter simple application which contains 2 multi line TextField's. The left one uses a default keyboard with Enter button. Its onSubmitted: method is not called, so you can not execute a method once the user has finished editing the TextField. The right TextField replaces Enter by Done, which enables onDubmitted. Since Enter is no longer available on the keyboard, I am asking how can I add a new line on the right multi line widget.

[image: App on Android Emulator]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Flutter TextField Multiple Lines'),
        ),
        body: const MyStatefulWidget());
  }
}

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  late TextEditingController _controllerEnter;
  late TextEditingController _controllerDone;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controllerEnter = TextEditingController();
    _controllerDone = TextEditingController();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controllerEnter.dispose();
    _controllerDone.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
        child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            width: 150,
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                const Text(
                  'Multiline TextField Enter',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                ),
                Focus(
                  child: TextField(
                    style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                    maxLines: 3,
                    controller: _controllerEnter,
                    onSubmitted: (String value) {
                      // method never called !
                      debugPrint('\n*** onSubmitted: $value ***\n');
                    },
                  ),
                  onFocusChange: (value) {
                    // this method compensate the fact that the
                    // TextField onSubmitted: method is not called.
                    if (!value) {
                      debugPrint('\n*** onFocusChange: ${_controllerEnter.text} ***\n');
                    }
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            width: 25,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 150,
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                const Text(
                  'Multiline TextField Done',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                ),
                TextField(
                  // How can Enter be used to add a new line to the TextField ?
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                  maxLines: 3,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                  textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                  controller: _controllerDone,
                  onSubmitted: (String value) {
                    debugPrint('\n*** onSubmitted: $value ***\n');
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: so you want the second text input have the same action(enter new line) like the first one ?

Comment: no, because if I add keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline, textInputAction: TextInputAction.newline, to the right TextField, then the onSubmitted: method will not be called. I would like to be able to add new lines AND have a method be called when I click on the Done button so that I can process the multiline TextField content.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do both with native keyboards.

You can maybe build a custom keyboard. For example, you could use a package like  https://pub.dev/packages/keyboard_actions

Answer (score 0):

have you tried  `textInputAction: TextInputAction.newline,`
just create a function that detect on what action needed so

```
 textInputAction: 
 isSubmit == true ? TextInputAction.done:
TextInputAction.newline,
```